# Configuring Wi-Fi in WIndows XP from Command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, wireless-networking

Sometimes it doesn't connect (especially to an ad-hoc network) unless I press rescan button.

How to control Wi-Fi connectivity in Windows XP from command line? (There's no 802.11-related things in XP's "netsh").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this guys have your answer:
http://code.mincus.com/31/windows-wireless-api/

> Executable Options:
>
> -Enable Enable the wireless interfaces specified by limit. If no limit
> specified, enable all wireless
> interfaces. This option effectively
> checks the “Use Windows to configure
> my wireless network settings” checkbox
> under the Wireless Network Connection
> Properties.
>
> -Add Path(s) to an XML file containing the information about the Wireless
> Access point that you wish to setup.
>
> -Delete Access Point name(s) that you wish to remove from the profile list.
>
> -Nics List wireless interfaces by their description and GUID.
>
> -Aps List access points by AP name.
>
> -Limit GUID of the interface(s) to limit the additions, deletions, and
> access point listings to. The default
> is to use all interfaces.

Sample Usage:

> Delete access point from
> all interfaces: wifi_config.exe
> -delete SAMPLE-AP
>
> Delete multiple access points from a
> specific interface: wifi_config.exe
> -delete SAMPLE-AP1 SAMPLE-AP2 -limit {GUID}
>
> Add multiple profiles: wifi_config.exe
> -add “C:\profile1.xml” “C:\profile2.xml”
>
> List access points: wifi_config.exe
> -aps

If not this one, I think this one is best:
http://www.wlanbook.com/enable-disable-wireless-card-command-line/

> The DevCon utility is a command-line utility that acts as an alternative to Device >Manager. Using DevCon, you can enable, disable, restart, update, remove, and query >individual devices or groups of devices. DevCon also provides information that is >relevant to the driver developer and is not available in Device Manager.
>
> You can use DevCon with Microsoft Windows 2000, Windows XP, and Windows Server 2003. >You cannot use DevCon with Windows 95, Windows 98, or Windows Millennium Edition.

Comment: Close to the thing I want, but not exactly.
What option is close to "Refresh Network List"? ("wifi_config -scan" doesn't exist, "wifi_config -aps" is not that thing.) How connect to existing access point?

This thing is more like command-line editor for "Advanced Network Settings", not a thing to trigger some actual scans or connects.

Answer (score 2):

You could potentially use devcon (a DOS program that can control devices in your system) to simulate unplugging and reconnecting the device.  This may cause it to reconnect.

I had a wireless USB adapter on a system that I did not have a keyboard/mouse connected to for a few years and had a batch file that would routinely check for internet access and if there was none, it would use devcon to cycle the USB device on/off.

Comment: Found standard "devcon" program. Trying to use it on particular device. "devcon disable" doesn't accept as arguments IDs that are returned by "devcon find" or "devcon listclass"...

Answer (score 0):

Check your wireless card manufacturer for tools included in the driver package or as an extra download. Sometimes the manufacturer will include extra goodies for use with their hardware, but you must search it out on their support web site.

As you have noticed, XP's netsh does not have the wireless support that Vista and above does. You could use VBScript to do this, but that is beyond my ability to assist you.