# command line tool to connect to wireless network on windows XP

Tags: wireless-networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Configuring Wi-Fi in WIndows XP from Command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/105022/configuring-wi-fi-in-windows-xp-from-command-line)

Is there any command line tool to connect to a wireless network on windows. 
I know netsh is not supported in win XP. Is there any open source command line tool ?

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/105022/configuring-wi-fi-in-windows-xp-from-command-line/115234

Answer (score 0):

Not that I have know of. Plenty of people have asked this question on the internet and I have not seen one with a working answer yet.

*However, a potential solution could be along the lines of:*

Windows XP does have an "Preferred" wireless connection setting which can cause it to autoconnect to a wireless network when it starts up.

If you can find the registry keys responsible for this you could create a *.reg file and have a batch program 'run' the *.reg file then do an `ipconfig /release` and then an `ipconfig /renew` to make it connect.

Note: I haven't tested this.

Answer (score 0):

Copy of the question:
[Configuring Wi-Fi in WIndows XP from Command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/105022/configuring-wi-fi-in-windows-xp-from-command-line/115234#115234)

I'll copy my answer here for those who land here:

I think this guys have your answer:
http://code.mincus.com/31/windows-wireless-api/

> Executable Options:
>
> -Enable Enable the wireless interfaces specified by limit. If no limit
> specified, enable all wireless
> interfaces. This option effectively
> checks the “Use Windows to configure
> my wireless network settings” checkbox
> under the Wireless Network Connection
> Properties.
>
> -Add Path(s) to an XML file containing the information about the Wireless
> Access point that you wish to setup.
>
> -Delete Access Point name(s) that you wish to remove from the profile list.
>
> -Nics List wireless interfaces by their description and GUID.
>
> -Aps List access points by AP name.
>
> -Limit GUID of the interface(s) to limit the additions, deletions, and
> access point listings to. The default
> is to use all interfaces.

Sample Usage:

> Delete access point from
> all interfaces: wifi_config.exe
> -delete SAMPLE-AP
>
> Delete multiple access points from a
> specific interface: wifi_config.exe
> -delete SAMPLE-AP1 SAMPLE-AP2 -limit {GUID}
>
> Add multiple profiles: wifi_config.exe
> -add “C:\profile1.xml” “C:\profile2.xml”
>
> List access points: wifi_config.exe
> -aps

If not this one, I think this one is best:
http://www.wlanbook.com/enable-disable-wireless-card-command-line/

> The DevCon utility is a command-line utility that acts as an alternative to Device >Manager. Using DevCon, you can enable, disable, restart, update, remove, and query >individual devices or groups of devices. DevCon also provides information that is >relevant to the driver developer and is not available in Device Manager.
>
> You can use DevCon with Microsoft Windows 2000, Windows XP, and Windows Server 2003. >You cannot use DevCon with Windows 95, Windows 98, or Windows Millennium Edition.